# change the use of SHBrowseForFolder and struct BROWSEINFO TO - IFileOpenDialog

Tags: c++, c, windows, function, interface

until now- in order to open a dialog box I used `SHBrowseForFolder` function. It causes some bugs and I was told to use `IFileOpenDialog`.
here is the code I need to replace:

```
bool wvFM::SelectFileSystemObjectDialogTree(const WCDialogCreationOptions& in_options,
                                            WCDialogReply& out_Reply)
{
    AUTO_FUNC_DEBUG;

    DWORD osErr = NO_ERROR;
    WTErr wtErr = eNoErr;

    out_Reply.accept = false;

    if(in_options.m_flags[WCDialogCreationOptions::eSelectFolder]) {
        BROWSEINFO bi = {0};
        bi.hwndOwner = (HWND)in_options.m_owner;
        bi.pidlRoot = NULL; // TBD by callback BrowseCallbackProc
        bi.lpszTitle = in_options.m_windowTitle.c_str();
        bi.ulFlags = BIF_USENEWUI;    // to enable pasting path
        bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc; // for initial dir option
        WTPathString initialLocationPathString(
            in_options.m_InitialDir.GetNativePathString());
        bi.lParam = in_options.m_InitialDir.IsValid()
                        ? (LPARAM)initialLocationPathString.c_str()
                        : NULL;

        LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

        // returns focus to the internal window of the plug
        ::SetFocus((HWND)in_options.m_owner);

        if(pidl != NULL) {
            TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
            SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, szPath);
            out_Reply.m_filePathRef = wvFM::WCStPath((char*)szPath);
            out_Reply.accept = true;
            IMalloc* imalloc = 0;
            if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&imalloc))) {
                imalloc->Free(pidl);
                imalloc->Release();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am not so sure of how to make that conversion.
Thanks to anyone who will help!

Comment: It looks like you are missing the end of the function. You have one opening brace more than the closing braces.

Comment: @danieloren What EXACTLY are you having trouble with when trying to convert this code from `SHBrowseForFolder()` to `IFileOpenDialog`? What have you tried so far that is not working for you?

Comment: @TedLyngmo since the code in question focuses on the case where the `eSelectFolder` flag is set, it stands to reason that the "missing" code you are refering to contain more code to handle the case where `eSelectFolder` is not set.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could be. The original indentation made it look like it was actually missing though.

Comment: @danieloren "*[SHBrowseForFolder] causes some bugs*" - what bugs exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly using a 3rd party library with some kind of custom string type, but you did not provide any details about what that string type actually is.  I'm *guessing* that string type is `char`-based, given that you are type-casting the result of `SHGetPathFromIDList()` to `char*` when assigning it to `out_Reply.m_filePathRef`, so you are likely compiling your project with `UNICODE` undefined so that `TCHAR` maps to `char` and not `wchar_t`.  In which case, `SHBrowseForFolder()` would be calling `SHBrowseForFolderA()` and not `SHBrowseForFolderW()`.

`IFileOpenDialog` does not deal with ANSI strings at all, only UNICODE strings, so you will have to convert back and forth between your 3rd party string type and Windows UTF-16 strings as needed.

The conversion of `SHBrowseForFolder()` to `IFileOpenDialog` would look *roughly* like the following (where `YourStringType` in `toWString()` is the 3rd party string type - make whatever adjustments you need where indicated):

```cpp
std::wstring toWString(const YourStringType &str)
{
    const char pStr = ... pointer to str's characters ...;
    int sLen = ... length of str in chars, not counting the null terminator ...;

    std::wstring ws;

    int wLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pStr, slen, NULL, 0);
    if (wLen > 0)
    {
        ws.resize(wLen);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pStr, sLen, ws.data(), wLen);
    }

    return ws;
}

std::string toString(const wchar_t *ws)
{
    std::string s;

    int wLen = lstrlenW(s);
    int sLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ws, wLen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (sLen > 0)
    {
        s.resize(sLen);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ws, wLen, s.data(), sLen, NULL, NULL);
    }

    return s;
}

IShellItem* toShellItem(const YourStringType &path)
{
    IShellItem *pItem = NULL;
    if (FAILED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(toWString(path).c_str(), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem))))
        pItem = NULL;
    return pItem;
}

bool wvFM::SelectFileSystemObjectDialogTree(const WCDialogCreationOptions& in_options,
                                            WCDialogReply& out_Reply)
{
    AUTO_FUNC_DEBUG;

    out_Reply.accept = false;

    if (in_options.m_flags[WCDialogCreationOptions::eSelectFolder]) {

        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen = NULL;
        if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFileOpen))))
            return false;

        FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS opts = 0;
        pFileOpen->GetOptions(&opts);
        
        pFileOpen->SetTitle(toWString(in_options.m_windowTitle).c_str());
        pFileOpen->SetOptions(opts | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

        IShellItem *pItem = toShellItem(in_options.m_InitialDir);
        if (pItem)
        {
            pFileOpen->SetFolder(pItem);
            pItem->Release();
        }

        HWND hwndOwner = (HWND) in_options.m_owner;

        HRESULT hr = pFileOpen->Show(hwndOwner);
        ::SetFocus(hwndOwner);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (SUCCEEDED(pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem)))
            {
                PWSTR pszFilePath;
                if (SUCCEEDED(pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath)))
                {
                    out_Reply.m_filePathRef = wvFM::WCStPath(toString(pszFilePath).c_str());
                    out_Reply.accept = true;
                    CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                }
                pItem->Release();
            }
        }

        pFileOpen->Release();
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```